# How to make selected an option of tag select in jquery without value

Tags: jquery, html

I need to make selected option 17 using JQuery
I can't use value, because it's always different.
So is there any solution to use number of 'select' child or somthing?
Thank you.

```
<select name="size" id="size">
    <option value="1430">17</option>
    <option value="1429">19</option>
    <option value="1428">20</option>
    <option value="1427">16</option>
    <option value="1426">15</option>
    <option value="1425">18</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$('select[name="size"] option').each(function() {
   if($(this).text() == '17') {
       $(this).prop('selected', true);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`:contains()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/):

```
$("#size").find("option:contains(17)").prop("selected",true);
```

Though that would pick up text like `1117` too. So you could use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) (with or with `$.trim()`):

```
$("#size option").filter(function() {
    return $.trim($(this).text()) === "17";
}).prop("selected", true);
```

Or a good old `.each()` loop will let you stop as soon as you find a matching item, so it's messier than `.filter()` but more efficient:

```
$("#size option").each(function() {
    if ($.trim($(this).text()) === "17") {
       $(this).prop("selected", true);
       return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Issue would be if there is an option with 117, 171 etc appear before this the option with value 17

Comment: @PSL - Yes, I was just editing that in...

Answer (score 0):

Jquery Makes developers life so easy   :)

```
var setstatus=17;
 $("#size option:contains(" + setstatus + ")").attr('selected', 'selected');
```